# Document attachement with PouchDB on NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, pouchdb

I have an AngularJS app that integrates PouchDB. I would like to add a document to the PouchDB but it is not very clear from the documentation (below):

```
 db.putAttachment(docId, attachmentId, rev, doc, type, [callback]);
```

> Attaches a binary object to a document. Most of PouchDB's API deals
>   with JSON, but if you're dealing with large binary data (such as
>   PNGs), you may incur a performance or storage penalty if you simply
>   include them as base64- or hex-encoded strings. In these cases, you
>   can store the binary data as an attachment. For details, see the
>   CouchDB documentation on attachments.
>
> Example Usage:

```
 var doc = new Blob(["It's a God awful small affair"]);
 db.putAttachment('a', 'text', rev, doc, 'text/plain', function(err, res) {})
```

> Within Node, you must use a Buffer instead of a Blob:

```
 var doc = new Buffer("It's a God awful small affair");
```

In my app, I got to the point where I have:

```
var file = document.getElementById('file');
```

Now, how do I use the Buffer to add my file to the DB? In addition, is it possible to automatically generate a valid docID, attachementID and rev? And what would be the type for a MS office document?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Blobs can definitely be confusing to work with.  For PouchDB, we wrote a [Blob shim library](https://gist.github.com/nolanlawson/10340255) that you're welcome to use, and that README also includes a few examples to get you started.  Basically you just need to pass in the blob data along with the content-type.

As an alternative, you can always just `update()` the document and add the attachment as a base64-encoded string to the `_attachments` object, which I often find easier.

**Edit:** whoops, didn't see that you're on Node.js.  Check out [this code](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/blob/f7476c61e62784192c05f184bfed5bbb22ce9c75/tests/utils.js#L43-L49) for an example of how we make Buffers/Blobs in the PouchDB unit tests.